# Saving nested has_many association based on dynamic checkboxes in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5, form-for

Code:

Business model

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :business_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :business_categories
  ......
end
```

Category Model

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :services
   has_many :business_categories
   has_many :businesses, through: :business_categories
   .....
 end
```

BusinessCategory Model

```
class BusinessCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :business
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :business_category_services
  has_many :services, through: :business_category_services
  ....
end

class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

and form which I want to design please have a look in below snapshot.

[please have a look on snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYlVf.png)

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Business' do
    f.input :name
    f.input :category_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: Category.all.map{|category| [category.name, category.id]}
    f.has_many :business_categories, :class=>'select_category', :heading=>'Services',  :new_record=> true do |business_category|
    business_category.input :service_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: Service.all.map{|service| [service.name, service.id]}, :input_html => { :class => 'services_checkboxes'}
  end
```

[in the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYlVf.png) as you can see - all the categories and services checkboxes are coming from categories and services table through `Category.all` and `Service.all.`

and the `service_ids` should be dynamic I mean I should see only those services which are based on chosen category in step 2 and not all of them.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

For new record(Business), you current form is fine but for edit your form should be something like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Business' do
  f.input :name
  Category.all.each |category| do
    check_box_tag :category_ids, category.id, @business.categories.include?(category), :name => 'business[category_ids][]'
    label_tag :category_ids, category.id
  end
  f.has_many :business_categories, :class=>'select_category', :heading=>'Services',  :new_record=> true do |business_category|
    Service.all.each |service| do
      check_box_tag :service_ids, service.id, business_category.services.include?(service), :name => 'business[business_categories][service_ids][]'
      label_tag :service_ids, service.id
    end
  end
end
```

Reference: http://millarian.com/rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/

Comment: @Muhammed for new record also my code is not working.

Comment: @Anand You can use this form for new record also please check the reference link!

Comment: @Muhammed for new record also my code is not right.

The snapshot shows is something like html design 
which I need to implement. 

And the reference which you shared is correct that 
category_ids=>[" ", "1", "2"] should pass in the params[:business] to save 
categories of a business. 

and it is happening in my case also  params=>{:business=>{:name=>"xyz", 
"category_ids"=>[" ", "1", "2"]}} and it will save the entries in join 
table business_categories because business has has many categories 

but I am stuck on saving the entries in join table of business_category and service

Comment: the ideally structure should be that I can select a single category using a select box and then choosed more than one service based on selected category through checkboxes and in that case params will be 

params=>{:business=>{:name=>"xyz", "business_categories_attributes"=>"0"=>
{["category_id"=>"1", "server_ids"=>["","2","3"]], 
"1"=>{["category_id"=>"2", "server_ids"=>["","4","5"]}}
}}

that will work.

But The requirment is that categories and services both should be in chekboxes. (please ignore my very first comment it was not complete.)

Comment: The flow is suppose I choosed 'Salon' and 'Skin care' categories through checkbox then via ajax only 'haircut' , 'hair spa', 'waxing' services checkboxes will display.

Comment: @Anand Did you add 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' in models ?